# How to show a drop-down menu over image?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to post code here recently, but it is working for some code posted only. So I would like to see my site [dropdown not show](http://navi.footballhighlightmm.netai.net/). In this site, the drop-down `Services` can't display its sub-menu. Please take a look at my site and guide me how to fix the dropdown menu?

**I tried to set z-index with various value but it's not working**.

[image]

Comment: The class name in Html (dropdown-menu) is different from the one is JavaScript (dropdown-submenu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stacking a dropdown menu over a picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323184/stacking-a-dropdown-menu-over-a-picture)

Comment: It doesn't solve mine ! Al least you should test with your though

Comment: Seems to show on mobile. CSS or HTML problem then.

Comment: Has something to do with navbar-collapse in from what I can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.navbar-default`. The submenu `ul` is overflowing the `div.navbar-default`, but you are hiding it.